# How to get shortest path between nodes on a grid?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, breadth-first-search

I want to calculate the shortest path between 2 nodes. Each node has position like [1,2]. When i iterate over nodes using BFS i mark each node as visited and add distance from start node. When end node is found I want to call a function, pass start and end node and get shortest path

input:

```
[3,3], [5,6], [all visited] (output included in all visited)
```

desired output:

```
[[3,4], [3,5], [3,6], [4,6]]
```

How do i filter all visited to get the shortest path?

Comment: If BFS is not a requirement, you can use DFS to maintain a stack and push nodes and pop out nodes when there is backtracking. The stack will depict the shortest path when you visit the destination node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are asking how you can reconstruct the shortest path from a breadth-first search that found a target.

There are several ways to do this, but one is to turn your visited-marking into a marking with a back reference to the node you came from.

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search#Pseudocode) you can find pseudo code where this back reference is a `parent` property of the node:

> ```
> procedure BFS(G, root) is
>      let Q be a queue
>      label root as discovered
>      Q.enqueue(root)
>      while Q is not empty do
>          v := Q.dequeue()
>          if v is the goal then
>              return v
>          for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
>              if w is not labeled as discovered then
>                  label w as discovered
>                  w.parent := v
>                  Q.enqueue(w)
> ```

Although you can keep a separate, boolean flag for "visited" (or "discovered"), you can save space by just using this `parent` property: if it is non-null, consider the node as visited.

Once you have found the target node, you can walk backwards via the `parent` back-reference property until you arrive at the starting node. It is not difficult to build the path while you walk back like that:

```
     if v is the goal then
         let path be a stack
         path.push(v)
         while v is not the root do
             v := v.parent
             path.push(v)
         return path
```

Note that depending of the actual data structure used for `path` you may need to reverse it.